# What does it mean when there are four tuples in a tf.pad function

Tags: image, tensorflow, padding, object-detection, yolo

I have this piece of code:

```
    padded_inputs = tf.pad(inputs, [[0, 0], [0, 0], [pad_beg, pad_end], [pad_beg, pad_end]])
```

It is for an image. I don't understand why there are four tuples since an image has width, height, and three color channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input data has 4 tuples like this `[batch_size, number_of_channels, height, width]`. So the `tf.pad` is not being implemented on first two bc you only need to pad height and width of the image. Sometimes, the channel number is also used at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I also just found this explanation in the TensorFlow documentation: When explicit padding is used and data_format is "NHWC", this should be in the form [[0, 0], [pad_top, pad_bottom], [pad_left, pad_right], [0, 0]]. When explicit padding used and data_format is "NCHW", this should be in the form [[0, 0], [0, 0], [pad_top, pad_bottom], [pad_left, pad_right]].